# How to avoid long delay when creating Kinesis Event Source for lambda function at TRIM_HORIZON

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

When re-creating a Kinesis event source for a Lambda function and setting the Kinesis pointer to TRIM_HORIZON, we often see delays of up to 15 minutes before the function starts to execute.

The lambda functions are JVM based, so we do have a startup delay of about 5 seconds, but that is nothing compared to the 15 minute delays we are seeing.  On the Kinesis Side,  We are using the standard Kinesis retention period of about 24 hours, and streams with between 10 and 30 shards. These streams will often have 10M+ of records on them.

I have 2 questions related to this:

1. Why is this happening (what about the lambda internals are causing the delay)?
2. What can we do (if anything) to avoid the delay?